# Proving inequality $ \frac{(x_1\cdot ...\cdot x_n)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{1+x_1+...+x_n}\leq \frac{1}{n+1} $

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove this estimation:
$$ \frac{(x_1\cdot ...\cdot x_n)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{1+x_1+...+x_n}\leq \frac{1}{n+1} $$ for all $ (x_1,...,x_n)\in M_c $ and all $ c\in ]0,\infty[ $ with $ M_c:=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in ]0,\infty[^n:\ c=x_1+...+x_n\}. $

My first idea was to show for a fixed $ c\in ]0,\infty[ $ and an arbitrary $ (x_1,...,x_n)\in M_c $

$$ \frac{x_1\cdot ...\cdot x_n}{1+c}\leq \frac{1}{(n+1)^{n+1}} $$

But I don't see how I can do this.

Comment: This is just AM-GM inequality for $\{1,x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$.

Comment: But I have to prove AM-GM with my task. And I don't know how to prove my inequality.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to find the maximum of $x_1\cdot x_2\cdot \ldots \cdot x_n$ over $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=c$, i.e. the maximum of $\sum \log(x_k)$ over $\sum x_k=c$. Since the logarithm is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, by Jensen's inequality the maximum is attained only at $x_1=\ldots=x_n=\frac{c}{n}$ and by setting $c=n r$
$$ \frac{\left(\prod x_k\right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{1+\sum x_k} \leq \frac{\left(\frac{c}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{n+1}}}{1+c} = \frac{r^{\frac{n}{n+1}}}{1+nr}=f(r).$$
It just remains to maximize $f(r)$, and this can be done in many ways, for instance through derivatives. The maximum occurs at $r=1$ and we are done.